# Dynamically plotting multiple plots to be displayed on one set of axes (one plot at a time)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35803853/how-to-make-a-function-non-blocking-dynamic-plotting-in-matlab-gui) I have a function that when run, updates 4 plots. This works as expected, except when I go to change which plot is displayed, it looks like there are remnants of the previously displayed plot. I go from a `bar` graph to a `surfc`, but I still see the bars across a flat plane. I am currently setting my data and drawing with

```
set(hplot2, 'yData', ME)
drawnow
```

Do I need to refresh the axes/plot somehow? I change which plot is on the axes with `set(plot1, 'Parent', axes1)`. I have no idea where is problem is arising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're switching between two plots you will either want to clear the axes prior to plotting the next thing using [`cla`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cla.html)

```
cla(axes1);
```

or you will want to simply toggle the visibility of the existing plot objects.

```
% To show only the bar plot
set(hbar, 'Visible', 'on')
set(hsurf, 'Visible', 'off')

% To show only the surf plot
set(hbar, 'Visible', 'off')
set(hsurf, 'Visible', 'on')
```

The root of the problem, is that an axes can actually hold *many* plots, so if you simply create a new plot and assign it as a child to an axes, the other plot objects are still there.

If you are creating entirely new graphics objects every time you plot something (by calling `bar` or `surfc`) using `cla` will be easiest. That being said, if you can adjust your code to simply update *existing* plot objects, that is ideal from both a performance and graphics management perspective.

Also, as another side note. I would discourage using `set(plot1, 'Parent', axes1)` after object creation. It is more robust to specify the [`Parent`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/barseries-properties.html#property_parent) property directly in the object constructor. This way you ensure that it goes *directly* to the axes you want.

```
plot1 = bar(data, 'Parent', axes1);
```

**Edit**

Now that I think about it, since you're toggling between 3D and 2D data, it *may* be easier to simply have **two** axes at the same location (one for the `bar` and one for the `surf`). You would then toggle the visibility of the axes on/off as needed. This way all of your view settings are preserved for a given axes.

```
barax = axes();
surfax = axes();

% Ensure they are located at the same position
link = linkprop([barax, surfax], 'Position');

hbar = bar(data, 'Parent', barax);
hsurf = surfc(data, 'Parent', surfax);

% Toggle these to switch plots.
set(barax, 'Visible', 'off')
set(surfax, 'Visible', 'on')
```